# REST on *just* IIS7 (without a webframework)

Tags: iis-7, webdav

I want to upload files directly to IIS7 (in this case I am using the WebRequest object in .NET). Thus I need IIS7 to accept POST, PUT, and DELETE verbs such that I can upload and delete files on the server directly. Is it possible to have IIS accept files without a a web framework like ASP.NET? Essentially I want to be able to use IIS (HTTP) as an FTP server.

Answer (score 1):

A web server by itself is not designed to do this, which is why the frameworks exist.  The closest option is to install and configure [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV).  WebDAV gives you most of the functionality you ask for.

The WebDAV module for IIS 7/7.5 appears to be completely rewritten to work with the new architecture of IIS 7.  Here's a link for the download and instructions for installing and configuring it.

[Installing and Configuring WebDAV on IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/350/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis-7/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Joseph Fultz has a blog post on MSDN on how to enable those verbs in IIS 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/joseph_fultz/archive/2009/07/23/enabling-the-put-verb-with-handlers-and-iis-7-0.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have IIS accept
>   files without a a web framework like
>   ASP.NET?

No. Especially given that IIS7 is in large parts written in .NET - what would be the sense of that? Driving a car without using any fuel?

If you would rup out the .NET framework (which ASP.NET is integral part of) IIS would not even start.

Comment: IIS 7 is native code - the .Net bits are all optional.